# I installed ubuntu MATE 15.10 without grub boot loader, now I want to use grub

Tags: grub2, restore, mate, ubuntu-mate

I had some drivers issues with standard ubuntu 14.04 so I tried to install ubuntu MATE to virual box in windows 10 first to try it. I liked it so I decided to dual boot it.

Some time age I installed standard ubuntu 14.04 besides windows 10 with grub and then I decided to format partition on which was ubuntu on because I had this drivers problems and hated it. But then I had to restore windows bootloader and it was a pain in the ass.

Last week I installed ubuntu MATE besides windows 10 WITHOUT grub bootloader with the help of this [video]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLw1bpIFec0 and managed to insert ubuntu MATE partition to boot in windows bootloader with easyBCD.

Everything works now, I like ubuntu MATE so much, that now I want boot directly into it, using grub first and then selecting windows 10 if I really want to boot into windows.

How things work now are like this: When I turn on my laptop it first loads something with windows logo and then prompts me at that windows blue screen if I want to load windows 10 or ubuntu MATE. Then I select ubuntu MATE and laptop restarts and loads into grub first, where I must select if I want to load ubuntu or windows again. After that I get in ubuntu MATE.

Everythign works now, but as I want to mainly use ubuntu now I want so shorted this process so that when I turn on my laptop it first gets me to grub where if I want, I boot into windows.

How can I do this? With this video tutorial which I mentioned, I installed grub to separate 400MB big Ext2 partion. Both OSes are on the same SSD both having 1/2 of capacity of this SSH (120GB both aprox.).

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a **new answer deriving from your comments** - reinstall the boot loaders.

First the Windows loader : Boot from the **Windows installation media**.
When the "**Install now**" screen appears select "**Repair your computer**".

Choose "**Troubleshoot**" then open "**Command prompt**" and execute :

```
bootrec.exe /fixboot  
bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
```

Now reboot into Windows installation and **disable hibernation** and **Fast Boot**.
To disable hibernation open **command prompt as administrator** and execute :

```
powercfg /h off
```

To disable Fast Boot open **Control Panel** (the old version - not the modern design),
select the **Energy Settings**, enable **show hidden settings** and **uncheck Fast Boot**.

After having done this **shutdown** the machine **completely** - do **NOT reboot** !

Now reinstall the GRUB boot loader to your Ubuntu installation  in **EFI mode**.

Boot from the Ubuntu installation media - open a terminal and execute:

```
    sudo mount /dev/sd*** /mnt
    sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt/boot/efi
    for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
    sudo chroot /mnt
    grub-install /dev/sd*
    update-grub
```

Note:

`sd*` = disk | `sd**` = efi partition | `sd***` = system partition

To identify the partition numbers use **GParted** - it is included in the Ubuntu installation media.

Boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu in UEFI settings to be the default operating system to boot.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to install `grub`.

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.

All you need is two commands. Enter them one at a time and  press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each one.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

The first command will install `grub`. `grub-install` will automatically pick the correct version of grub. The second updates your `grub` menu.

This should be all that you need. The `grub` menu should show up when you reboot.

But if you do not see the `grub` menu when you reboot, you may need to enter your EFI (Bios) settings in order to choose Ubuntu to be first in the boot order. (This setting is *not* the same as the hardware boot order: usb, cd, hdd, etc.) How to enter the EFI setup (often <kbd>esc</kbd> during boot) and the location for the boot order setting varies for each manufacturer.

Comment: Hmmm, now I deleted ubuntu option in easyBCD but now when I select windows 10 option in grub it doesn't load into it, just some gray screen appears and does nothing.

What did it go wrong?

Comment: I don't want to use easyBCD anymore. I'll try.

Comment: I tried but when I select windows 10, it shows only ubuntu MATE option but when I select this it get's me an error. I think I must repair windows bootloader?

Comment: I would run update-grub again in ubuntu. That really should take care of it and let you choose and boot windows from the grub menu. Let me know.